# Run a powershell script exactly like a batch command

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch, cmd.exe

How can I get the effect of running a powershell script from a batch command.

e.g. I have a few batch commands on PATH specific to my user, I use these to make using the command line & git easier for my job.

However I havn't gotten into the habit of learning PowerShell yet, so don't like using PowerShell if I can help it.

However as stuff migrates, more and more scripts appear to be powershell scripts.

How can I create a 'shortcut' batch file, that forwards all arguments passed to it, to a powershell script of the same name?

E.g. I have a Powershell script called stree.ps1

`Start-Process "C:\Users\ryan.leach\AppData\Local\SourceTree\SourceTree.exe"  -ArgumentList "-f $((Resolve-Path $args[0]).toString())"`

that will launch SourceTree with the argument corresponding to a passed in path.

How can I create a stree.bat that calls stree.ps1 forwarding all arguments to stree.ps1, without having to update stree.bat if small changes are made to stree.ps1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `stree.ps1` in PowerShell like this:

```
stree some_argument
```

then your `stree.bat` should look like:

```
PowerShell -Command "stree some_argument"
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6) for more details.

Edit: I haven't tested it, but I assume you would pass the arguments in the same way as with any other batch script:

```
PowerShell -Command "stree %*"
```

and then run:

```
stree.bat some_argument some_other_argument
```

Edit 2: Ok, I tested it and it works like expected.

Comment: How can you flow the arguments in? Hard coding is easy enough.

Comment: I assume like in any other batch script - see my edit.